# Conflict when updating a document with both $set and $currentDate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I’m using Mongo 3.6.3 and I have a database with a collection and an item with `_id` equal to `1`.

I want to update the item by adding an object and a timestamp *inside* of that object. However, I get an error. Here’s what I do:

```
function MyObject() {
    this.bar = {
        apples: 4,
        bananas: 5
    };
}

collection.update({
    _id: 1
}, {
    $set: {
        "foo": new MyObject()
    },
    $currentDate: {
        "foo.time": {
            $type: 'timestamp'
        }
    }
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err.name, err.message);
});
```

and I get:

> MongoError Updating the path 'foo.time' would create a conflict at 'foo'

**Why does that happen?**

If I run the `$set` operation first and then the `$currentDate` one in another `update()`, I get the desired result:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "foo" : {
        "bar" : {
            "apples" : 4,
            "bananas" : 5
        },
        "time" : Timestamp(1523459420, 1)
    }
}
```

However, if I try to do them simultaneously like I’ve shown in the code above, I get the error. **Why?**

Answer (score 3):

You can't have multiple operators (`$set` and `$currentDate`) that modify the same path (`foo` in this case). In your case you could use dot notation though:

```
collection.update({
    _id: 1
}, {
    $set: {
        "foo.bar.apples": 4,
        "foo.bar.bananas": 5
    },
    $currentDate: {
        "foo.time": {
            $type: 'timestamp'
        }
    }
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err.name, err.message);
});
```

or just change `MyObject` to set `this.time = new Date()` instead of using `$currentDate`.